# Change the theme colour while using Stripe's paymentLauncher.confirm to confirm and add the card

Tags: android, stripe-payments

Currently I am adding the support of SCA using Stripe payment gateway. I have updated the library and currently using the custom view to add the card. As per the stripe [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse-cards-only?platform=android) I am using `paymentLauncher.confirm` to confirm the card and it will start the SCA auth flow if card is required authentication. When I am calling the confirm method of SDK, statusbar colour of my Android app change to the different one (stipe's default) colour.

Is there any way to set the theme for the stripe when confirm the card? Please check the screenshots.

**Before calling paymentLauncher.confirm:**

[image]

**After calling paymentLauncher.confirm:**

[image]

**What I have tried:**
Tried by using overriding the activity and theme:

```
<activity android:name="com.stripe.android.view.PaymentMethodsActivity"
            android:theme="@style/StripeDefaultTheme"/>
```

Theme:

```
<style name="StripeDefaultTheme" parent="StripeBaseTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/xxx</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/xxx</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/xxx</item>
        <item name="titleTextColor">@color/xxx</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/xxx</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You might could try doing something similar to this: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues/414#issuecomment-333606873. If that doesn't work, you could open up a separate issue on Github for this.

Comment: @codename_duchess Already tried that but it's not working.